# How do i print on the next line on programed linear layout in kotlin android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

/* Im trying to learn kotlin for android develop and i'm stuck because i can't move to the next line of printing this i what i'm tring to print o three lines:*/

```
val

Sist:LinearLayout=findViewById(R.id.Afisaj)

Sist.addView(Textul)

Sist.addView(a)

Sist.addView(Textul1)

Sist.addView(b)

Sist.addView(Textul2)

Sist.addView(c)

Sist.addView(Textul3)

Sist.addView(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Kotlin. Linearlayout's default orientation is horizontal so if you want to arrange the views vertically you need to set the orientation to vertical

Comment: ok thanks. and i'm sorry for bothering you... but now i'm starting to learn android dev